Transferring files from a Wacom tablet to a Windows PC through Bluetooth
I have a discontinued Wacom tablet that uses a mobile app to function. It is a paper to digital tablet and I would like to use it for my note taking needs in uni. I already have a latex-ish system in place for all my notes that uses a python script (or will when I finish it) to organize and create all my notes, but I digress. Suffice it to say that the ability to add in quick sketches would be pretty cool.
This tablet is a bit weird. It can connect to desktop, but requires its specific app to access the output (which is a single json file with the recording of the pen coordinates and pressure), the same app that you can find on the mobile app store. In the manual it also says to connect it specifically to mobile, but I don't see why that should stop me. Most of the features of the Wacom app are locked behind a paywall (that goes without saying) and I cannot even find the directory in which it saves the sketches that it downloads off of the tablet whenever it syncs. (Did I mention that it no longer supports my tablet and it's been working so far off of fossil code, because it is; so if I kinda have to figure this out).
When I tried to first connect it to Windows through the built in interface, it would show connected for a split second and then revert back to "unconnected" but "paired" state (in the sense that windows registered it as a know bluetooth device). I think this is due to an authentication built-in the tablet itself.
Ideally I would like to go around the Wacom app entirely and access the output.json directly, but as an alternative I could keep the Wacom app open in the background and then retrieve the file from its directory whenever I need it. The problem is that I cannot find the directory to which it saves its files (I have looked in Programs and Programs (x86) as well as AppData and the app's own folders in Windows apps, but nothing).
On the bright side I do have access to the JavaScript source code of the app so theoretically I could fake the authentication and get the output.json file that way. One small problem: I don't know anything about js, I am already new to python and I'm kinda struggling to write a simple app so I have no idea where to look in the 20k lines of code (I tried searching for "pair", "device(s)" and I did find a few functions but I cannot figure out anything beyond that).
I have a friend that introduced me to this method, and also explained more or less how the tablet works under the hood (very simply), though he didn't mention anything about the authentication (although he did say he used Linux and I haven't tried that yet, but I also still need to learn Linux).
P.S. If anyone is interested, the app's name is Wacom Inkspace App, and I downloaded it from the Microsoft store.

Hello, The first thing I'm gonna ask, are you sure the temp file have to permission to receive file from other devices, windows local temp folder isn't made for this so you might have to play with the perm arround.

@Maslie I wasn't aware such permissions existed actually. It's my first time tinkering with multiple connected devices. Where can I change these permissions for folders? What are they called? In proprieties there are only permissions for users (system and admin) and they are all checked.

After the edits, the question becomes confusing. It would be better to rewrite this question (not create a new one), with just what is currently needed to resolve the issue.

@DrMoishePippik Edited it, I hope it's clearer now

Are you sure the application is not what is generating the json file? Based on what you describe that is the ONLY thing that could be generating it (in my humble opinion).

You reference "app" several times and I don't think you're always referring to the same one. Inkscape, for instance, is a relatively well known drawing program, NOT a Wacom tablet communication utility. Please EDIT your post to make it more clear which app you're referring to each time. Second, use a tool like ProcMon (from Microsoft Sysinternals) to watch all system actions while the app is running, filtering for the apps processes, to help you find where it's dropping things.

@Ramhound I don't think so. The tablet works such that every time you make some changes, it sets a flag (I think) and changes the LED light to indicate it. Then when you press the (only) button on the tablet, if it is connected to a device it is going to export the json of the changes. The thing is you don't need the app open. I have made several singular exports while it was on but nominally not connected to my pc and it still exported multiple pages to the app once I opened it and it connected automatically. I don't know if they are stored locally on the tablet or somewhere on the pc though.

@music2myear Cleared up the bit about the app: it's Wacom Inkscape, with a whoping 1.9 stars on the MS store. It's only one app I'm referring to throughout the whole post

So I found somewhat of a solution and I'm gonna post it here for the sake of anyone who is going through my same problem.
A friend of mine found this github repo that could fix this. It's github.com/tuhiproject/tuhi and is almost entirely written in Python. Though it is built for Linux, since it uses bluez and Windows is not as dev friendly with their bluetooth apparently.
I am not good with Python or programming, but when I'll have time I'll try to look into it and port it to Windows. The bulk of the work (interfacing with the device) is done so I'd only have to figure out pybluez, which is a python module to interface with bluetooth, but apparently supports up to windows 8.1 but can be installed for windows 10 (idk about 11).
I'm gonna consider this problem solved and I'm not going to this thread anymore, if anyone has the same problem, know that there really doesn't seem to be a simple solution.
